# Why Kendo Treeview Not Updating Remote Data From Datasource?

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm biding a treeview to a remote data and at this point the data is displayed correctly. The problem: when I change the data in the database and refresh my page, the treeview doesn't reflect the new data. It seems that the treeview is not calling the json action anymore after the first load.
This is my treeview code:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
.Name("MyTree")
.DataTextField("Title1")
.LoadOnDemand(true)
.ExpandAll(true)
.Events(a => a.Select("MyTreeSelect"))

.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
.Read(read => read
.Action("MainTree", "SendData")))))
```

Answer (score 0):

After several hours of trying, adding the following model solved my problem. It seems that the different version was the main problem.

```
.Model(e =>
{
    e.Id("Id");
    e.HasChildren("HasChildren");
}
```